Add a custom field for sorting the products in a specific category WOOCOMMERCE
I’d like to add a custom field for sorting the products in a specific category.
I have some products that are visible in different categories and I need that these products will be sort in different order depending by the choosen category.
Let’s say I have 3 products which are on categories A B and C
I need that the page of category A shows products in the order 1 2 3, category B 2 3 1 and category C 3 2 1.
I’d prefer a simple way without the need of external plugin…
Thanks in advance!

No one can help me? please !

The reason you're not getting any traction here is because your question is open ended and could be solved multiple ways. You are basically asking someone to come up with a solution for you - the way WPSE is supposed to work is that you write your code and when you encounter a problem you ask for help with your code.  Asking "can someone tell me how to do X" isn't going to get you an answer unless someone happens to have the solution already written or at least something very similar.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
